# TensorFlow Model takes exponential time on large dataSet

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pyspark, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow for Poets to detect features in clothing images. I have trained 4 different models(sleeve, shape, length & hemline). Now i pass image urls to each of the model and store the result. Since i have huge data (100k images), so using spark to broadcast 4 models once  and passing image RDD to detect the features. It's taking exponential time. It starts from 3 secs/images & keep increasing the execution time. When scripts already sensed 10k images, its execution time reaches to 8 secs/ images. I am new to Tensorflow, will be very thankful if get any idea to make the execution time linear.

```
def getLabelDresses(file_name):
    resultDict = {}
    t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                              input_height=input_height,
                              input_width=input_width,
                              input_mean=input_mean,
                              input_std=input_std)
    input_name = "import/" + input_layer
    output_name = "import/" + output_layer



    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

        graph_def.ParseFromString(model_data_hemline.value)

        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

        input_operation_hemline = g.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation_hemline = g.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            results = sess.run(output_operation_hemline.outputs[0],{input_operation_hemline.outputs[0]: t})

        results = np.squeeze(results)

        top_k = results.argsort()[-1:][::-1]
        labels = load_labels(label_file_hemline)
        resultDict['hemline'] = labels[top_k[0]]

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

        graph_def.ParseFromString(model_data_shape.value)

        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

        input_operation_shape = g.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation_shape = g.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            results = sess.run(output_operation_shape.outputs[0],{input_operation_shape.outputs[0]: t})

        results = np.squeeze(results)

        top_k = results.argsort()[-1:][::-1]
        labels = load_labels(label_file_shape)
        resultDict['shape'] = labels[top_k[0]]

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

        graph_def.ParseFromString(model_data_length.value)

        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

        input_operation_length = g.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation_length = g.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            results = sess.run(output_operation_length.outputs[0],{input_operation_length.outputs[0]: t})

        results = np.squeeze(results)

        top_k = results.argsort()[-1:][::-1]
        labels = load_labels(label_file_length)
        resultDict['length'] = labels[top_k[0]]

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

        graph_def.ParseFromString(model_data_sleeve.value)

        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

        input_operation_sleeve = g.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation_sleeve = g.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            results = sess.run(output_operation_sleeve.outputs[0],{input_operation_sleeve.outputs[0]: t})

        results = np.squeeze(results)

        top_k = results.argsort()[-1:][::-1]
        labels = load_labels(label_file_sleeve)
        resultDict['sleeve'] = labels[top_k[0]]     

    return resultDict;


model_file_hemline = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/hemline/retrained_graph_hemline.pb"
label_file_hemline = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/hemline/retrained_labels_hemline.txt"
model_file_length = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/length/retrained_graph_length.pb"
label_file_length = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/length/retrained_labels_length.txt"
model_file_shape = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/shape/retrained_graph_shape.pb"
label_file_shape = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/shape/retrained_labels_shape.txt"
model_file_sleeve = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/sleeve/retrained_graph_sleeve.pb"
label_file_sleeve = "/home/ubuntu/amit/feature-sensing/tf_files/attribute/dresses/sleeve/retrained_labels_sleeve.txt"

with gfile.FastGFile(model_file_hemline, "rb") as f:
    model_data = f.read()
    model_data_hemline = sc.broadcast(model_data)
with gfile.FastGFile(model_file_length, "rb") as f:
    model_data = f.read()
    model_data_length = sc.broadcast(model_data)
with gfile.FastGFile(model_file_shape, "rb") as f:
    model_data = f.read()
    model_data_shape = sc.broadcast(model_data)
with gfile.FastGFile(model_file_sleeve, "rb") as f:
    model_data = f.read()
    model_data_sleeve = sc.broadcast(model_data)

def calculate(row):
    path = "/tmp/"+row.guid
    url = row.modelno
    print(path, url)
    if(url is not None):
        import urllib.request
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)
        t1=time.time() 
        result = getLabelDresses(path)
        print(time.time()-t1)
        print(result)
        return row
    return row

product2.rdd.map(calculate).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `getLabelDresses` in your code adds operations to the graph.

Split your code into setup (model loading) part, executed once and execution part that is executed for each image. The latter should only contain calls to `Session.run`.

Another option is to clear graph before processing next image using [`tf.reset_default_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph). But it is less preferable.